# Calling a function in functional component from a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-component, react-functional-component

Say I have a Child component which is a functional component and a function a():

```
export default function child({ ... }) {
 
   ...

   function a() {
      ...
   }

...

}
```

and say I also have a parent which is a React.Component and the parent of the child component:

```
class parent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.child= React.createRef();
    }
    
     render() {
         return(
              <child ref = {this.child}/>
         )
    }
}
```

I am trying to call function a() from the parent component. I am aware that this is against the recommended React structure, but is there a way to How can I accomplish so?

Thank you.

Comment: So you're trying to call function a() of child component in parent component?

Comment: You can re-design and move function a to the parent, and pass that function to the child as props. If you share a minimal reproducible example (codesandbox would be great) it would be better.

Comment: You can pass a function from a parent to a child component, but not the reverse

Answer (score 1):

Your parent component won't be aware of the function `a()` as it is scoped to your child (functional) component.

A different way to handle this, assuming you're only dealing with this single parent/child structure, would be to declare your function `a()` in the parent, then pass it to the child.

If the function is something that is likely needed in multiple, unrelated  components, then exporting the function separately as a 'helper' function would allow it to be imported and used in different places.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `a` function outside the `child` function.

```js
export function a() {
  ...
}

export default function child({ ... }) {
  a();
  ...
}
```

This way you can call `a` function inside the `child` function and you can also import it in some other component.
Btw. React components should start with capital letter → `function Child({...})`